# Ajax get message problem

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm sending some message through Ajax, using encodeURIComponent but in the server side I getting some unwanted character in the message for example instead of the

> can't

I'm getting

> can\'t

What is the solution for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this answer:

```
<?php 
// first use encodeURIComponent on javascript to encode the string 
// receive json string and prepare it to json_decode 
$jsonStr = stripslashes ($_POST['action']); 
// decode to php object 
$json = json_decode ($jsonStr); 

// $json is now a php object 
?>
```

Given from:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: The `urldecode` page has an example with `stripslashes` and `json_decode` in it but without `urldecode`? That's very cool.

Comment: This does fix the OP's problem, but it's a hack since PHP shouldn't be adding slashes to values in the request anyway. If you make sure that http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc is turned off, as it should be since it's deprecated, you won't need to remove slashes that were added.

Answer (score 1):

Quotes do not get escaped by encodeURIComponent. namuol is correct, your framework is trying to be very smart for you and applying its own escaping to everything passed through POST and GET. If using PHP, make sure [Magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) is turned off, it's now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance that the framework you're using is proactively trying to prevent SQL Injection attacks by escaping the single-quote character by default. Look into the documentation for your framework for a way to get the verbatim text from the POST data.